# How can `git log --all` miss a commit point?

Tags: git

After a commit I am reminded I'm in a detached HEAD state.

```
> git commit -m "Implemented Runrealfast algorithm"
[detached HEAD af46ac9] Implemented Runrealfast algorithm
2 files changed, 18 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)
```

I ignore the detached HEAD and backtrack to a couple of commit points:

```
> git checkout 87e147e
> git stash -u
> git checkout ed157a3
```

while running a `git stash -u` along the way.

Eventually I try to find the commit SHA I had made earlier

```
> git log --all | grep Runrealfast
(no output)
```

but `git log --all` does not show it.

Luckily my Terminal has a full history. I identify from the Terminal's messages the relevant SHA and run:

```
> git checkout af46ac9
```

and the commit in question shows up with no problem.

How can `git log --all` miss a commit point? Is a detached HEAD also a dangling commit?

Comment: By checking out commits `87e147e` and `ed157a3` you've moved `HEAD` away from `af46ac9`, therefore it's not referenced anymore and not reached by `git log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several reasons `--all` could miss a commit.  That may sound strange, but the thing is `--all` doesn't mean *all commits*.

Rather `--all` means "all refs".  So you get the (simplified) history of the current `HEAD` commit, plus every branch, every tag, every remote-tracking branch, every backup ref created by `filter-branch`, the most recent stash, and maybe some other odds and ends.  (Why "simplified"?  I'll come back to that.)

But your commit is none of those.  You asked: *"Is a detached HEAD also a dangling commit?"*  And the answer is: *No*... but in your case, sort of.

Detached head just means that you're not currently on any branch.  You might be on a dangling commit. Or you might be on a commit that's in the history of one or more refs, but got there by checking out with a remote branch ref name, a SHA ID, a tag name, etc., instead of a branch name.

But certainly if you're in detached head state and you make a new commit, that new commit starts out as a dangling commit.

In that situation, the most reliable way to find the commit is to look at the reflog for `HEAD`

```
git reflog
```

or, if you want the output to look like `git log` output,

```
git log --reflog
```

This can only be counted upon within the repo where the dangling commit was created (which is probably the only repo that has the commit anyway), within a reasonable time after the commit was created (the reflogs eventually expire), and on the assumption that you haven't expressly damaged the commit logs (with a command that forces reflog expiry, or by messing with the `.git/logs` directory).

By the way, when I said the history was "simplified": There are times when `git log --all` will skip a commit even though it *is* in the history of a ref.  This is because git determines that it can explain the current state of the file at each ref without including the offending commit.  For a detailed explanation of what git means by this, see the `git log` docs; if you want to make sure you see every non-dangling commit, you have to add `--full-history` as well as `--all`

Answer (score 2):

From the [Git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log):

> **--all**
>
> Pretend as if all the refs in `refs/`, along with `HEAD`, are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.

The commit from your previous detached HEAD is not a [ref](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-References) (loosely speaking, it doesn't have a name), thus isn't listed.

Note that if you want to get back to that commit, `git reflog` may be a more convenient aid than hoping you'll find it via terminal archaeology!