# Git log suddenly misses commits (with --after)?

Tags: git

Found something similar here:

[How can `git log --all` miss a commit point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44639557/how-can-git-log-all-miss-a-commit-point)

... but it deals with dangling commits, which is not the problem I have here. (this is on git version 2.17.1, Ubuntu 18.04)

Basically, I have been working with a script, that automatically creates a small git repo, with empty commits and fixed timestamps; I must have deleted and recreated this repo at least 100 times this evening.

Up to some 20 minutes ago, the behavior was the same - this is what the whole history looks like (EDIT: added `--graph`, to show it is plain linear history, no branching):

```
$ git --no-pager log --graph --all --pretty='%ad %cd %h'
* Wed Jul 4 16:56:04 2018 +0000 Wed Jul 4 16:56:04 2018 +0000 bec8f1c
* Wed Jul 4 16:10:24 2018 +0000 Wed Jul 4 16:10:24 2018 +0000 dd51181
* Wed Jun 20 18:31:47 2018 +0000 Wed Jun 20 18:31:47 2018 +0000 8b7ca2a
* Wed Jun 20 18:11:11 2018 +0000 Wed Jun 20 18:11:11 2018 +0000 9a32592
* Wed Jun 20 17:10:17 2018 +0000 Wed Jun 20 17:10:17 2018 +0000 2454ee0
* Wed Jun 20 16:56:22 2018 +0000 Wed Jun 20 16:56:22 2018 +0000 b77dee4
* Tue Jun 19 21:40:13 2018 +0000 Tue Jun 19 21:40:13 2018 +0000 c9dc470
* Tue Jun 19 19:20:31 2018 +0000 Tue Jun 19 19:20:31 2018 +0000 baceab3
* Tue Jun 19 18:30:11 2018 +0000 Tue Jun 19 18:30:11 2018 +0000 89ab6c2
* Tue Jun 19 17:35:19 2018 +0000 Tue Jun 19 17:35:19 2018 +0000 a95553d
* Thu Jun 14 10:01:05 2018 +0000 Thu Jun 14 10:01:05 2018 +0000 c61c8fc
* Thu Jun 14 09:19:41 2018 +0000 Thu Jun 14 09:19:41 2018 +0000 2046e07
* Thu Jun 14 08:26:38 2018 +0000 Thu Jun 14 08:26:38 2018 +0000 f205435
* Thu Jun 14 08:26:29 2018 +0000 Thu Jun 14 08:26:29 2018 +0000 d4c70f1
* Wed Jun 13 19:20:16 2018 +0000 Wed Jun 13 19:20:16 2018 +0000 28a5a55
```

I get the same output for `git --no-pager log --all --pretty='%ad %h' --after 2018-06-13` (I though "after" 2018-06-13 would mean that no commits from 2018-06-13 would be included, but that is not so: the "Wed Jun 13" commit still gets listed with `--after 2018-06-13`).

Anyways, so for the most of the evening, `--after 2018-06-14` started from `Thu Jun 14 08:26:29`, and included all four commits from `Thu Jun 14`, and all those after; basically, it looked like this:

```
$ git --no-pager log --all --pretty='%ad %h' --after 2018-06-14
Wed Jul 4 16:56:04 2018 +0000 bec8f1c
Wed Jul 4 16:10:24 2018 +0000 dd51181
Wed Jun 20 18:31:47 2018 +0000 8b7ca2a
Wed Jun 20 18:11:11 2018 +0000 9a32592
Wed Jun 20 17:10:17 2018 +0000 2454ee0
Wed Jun 20 16:56:22 2018 +0000 b77dee4
Tue Jun 19 21:40:13 2018 +0000 c9dc470
Tue Jun 19 19:20:31 2018 +0000 baceab3
Tue Jun 19 18:30:11 2018 +0000 89ab6c2
Tue Jun 19 17:35:19 2018 +0000 a95553d
Thu Jun 14 10:01:05 2018 +0000 c61c8fc
Thu Jun 14 09:19:41 2018 +0000 2046e07
Thu Jun 14 08:26:38 2018 +0000 f205435
Thu Jun 14 08:26:29 2018 +0000 d4c70f1
```

However, in the past 20 minutes, it simply stopped returning `Thu Jun 14 08:26:29`, `Thu Jun 14 08:26:38` and `Thu Jun 14 09:19:41` for the same command - so now what I effectively get is this:

```
$ git --no-pager log --all --pretty='%ad %h' --after 2018-06-14
Wed Jul 4 16:56:04 2018 +0000 bec8f1c
Wed Jul 4 16:10:24 2018 +0000 dd51181
Wed Jun 20 18:31:47 2018 +0000 8b7ca2a
Wed Jun 20 18:11:11 2018 +0000 9a32592
Wed Jun 20 17:10:17 2018 +0000 2454ee0
Wed Jun 20 16:56:22 2018 +0000 b77dee4
Tue Jun 19 21:40:13 2018 +0000 c9dc470
Tue Jun 19 19:20:31 2018 +0000 baceab3
Tue Jun 19 18:30:11 2018 +0000 89ab6c2
Tue Jun 19 17:35:19 2018 +0000 a95553d
Thu Jun 14 10:01:05 2018 +0000 c61c8fc
```

What happened, why would these commits not be working anymore? I guess it would be more understandable if this was a larger repo, with many branches/contributors etc, so more chances to reach an inconsistent state - but in this case, there's not even any content in it, just empty commits?! And it cannot even get to any inconsistent state, because I keep deleting it and recreating it from a script ???!!

Does anyone know what could possibly be the reason for this, and how do I get git to again show all of the commits on Thu Jun 14 with `--after 2018-06-14`, as I got it with previous invocations of that command?!

Btw, the above linked post does mention `--full-history`, but it doesn't help much here:

```
git --no-pager log --full-history --all --pretty='%ad %h' --after 2018-06-14
```

... returns the exact same results, that I posted above for the invocation without `--full-history`.

EDIT: I can go back to showing all those four commits if I use `--after '2018-06-14 00:00:00'`, but I am 100% positive I never used this command in this form before I got this problem. Could it be, that if you don't specify hours in `--after`, `git` might end up randomly assigning them - and I was just "lucky" most of the night, if `git` randomly picked `00:00:00` to fill out the hours?

Comment: What is the parent of c61c8fc ? 2046e07 ?

Comment: Many thanks, @NoDataFound - yes it is, I just did `gitk c61c8fc` and can copy-paste `Parent: 2046e0729...` from there; it is a plain linear history, no branches, no different users (also added `--graph` to first command in OP to show that)

Comment: Be aware that `--after` / `--since` use the *committer* date, too, not the author date. (In this case they're the same, so it doesn't matter,but in other cases, it does matter.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git's date parser uses local time as the base, try specifying `--after 2018-06-13T00:00Z` for midnight zulu (or leave off the Z for midnight local).

Comment: Thanks for that @jthill - I was suspecting something going haywire with timestamps, too...